# Как поставить footer по назначению снизу

Tags: html, css

Вот мой код - https://codepen.io/xlabuchik/pen/wepgBV

**Вопрос:** почему я должен задавать `top` `footer`у, если по идее он должен находится в самом низу, а если я убираю ему присвоенный класс из css он находится в левом верхним углу?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body
{
 font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
background:url(https://img.gazeta.ru/files3/37/8002037/01WIKI.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size:100%;
 background-attachment:fixed; 
}
#inp{
  background:#FFEBCD;
    font-size:27px;
}
#qq{
   text-align:center;
  top:200px;
}
.p{
  color:black;
  font-size:110px; 
}
.a{
  color:#0000FF;
  font-size:30px;
  text-decoration:none;
}
#but{
  background:Wheat;
   border-radius: 35px;

  color:black;
  font-size:35px;
}
#but:hover{
   background:#EEE8AA;
   cursor: pointer;
   border-radius: 40px;
  box-shadow: 20px 0px 20px 0px    #8B0000;
}
#but2{
  background:Wheat;
   border-radius: 35px;

  color:black;
  font-size:35px;
}
#but2:hover{
  background:#EEE8AA;
   cursor: pointer;
   border-radius: 40px;
  box-shadow: 20px 0px 20px 0px    #0000FF;
}
footer {
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
   top: 500px;
  text-align:center;
 font-size:25px;
  background-color: #BC8F8F;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
footer:hover{
   background-color: #FA8072;
}
#back {
  background-color: Wheat;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
#back:hover {
  background-color: #EEE8AA;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  opacity: 0.9;

}
```

```html
<html>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<meta http-equip="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> 
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Frijole|Lobster|Pacifico|Monoton" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bowlby+One" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
<body>
 <div class="container-fluid" id="qq">
   <div id="back">
<p class="p">Wikipedia Viewer</p>
   </div>
<input class="vedi" id="inp">
<button id="but" class=" btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true" style="color: red"></i>Search</button>
   <button id="but2" onclick="random()" class=" btn btn-primary">Random</button> 
   <div id="petro"></div>

   </div> 
   <footer class="container-fluid">Copyright ©<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sergey.karachik" target="_blank">xlabuchik</a> 2017. All rights reserved. </footer> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Внутри `<div class="container-fluid" id="qq">` и `<footer class="container-fluid">` есть `position: relative;` который наследует твой футер.

Нужно удалить `class="container-fluid"`

Добавть в footer

```
footer {
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KqoGxr

Comment: согласен но он всеровно стает не в нижней точке страницы

Comment: обновлён ответ.

Comment: большое спасибо codename0082016 за подсказку все работает!